# Highcharts (HighMap) showing cities on county click

Tags: javascript, highcharts, drilldown

http://www.highcharts.com/maps/demo/map-drilldown

In High chart Maps, when we click on state it shows all of its county. Is there a way that i click on a county and it shows all of it cities? Is there any way of accomplishing it. I want to do it for US. Can someone provide a sample code.

Comment: It is possible but you need to havethe maps you want to show in the right format. All available predefined map collections can be found here https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/. If you cannot find the map you're looking for you can create a custom map. It is explained in Highcharts docs how to do it https://www.highcharts.com/docs/maps/custom-maps

Comment: I have been wanting for USA cities. The maps that are available are upto the county level

Comment: Then you need to create a custom map (see the link I posted above). You can also post the idea on Highcharts uservoice https://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api

Comment: Yes, a map for US Cities in Highmaps would be quite useful